# How can I improve MySQL Insert Performance using MySQL C++ Connector?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am inserting a lot of records to a MySQL database and I'm trying to achieve decent INSERT performance.  I am using MySQL 8.0 with the MySQL Connector C++ 8.0.

In order to determine the fastest way to insert my data, I built a small test program that simply inserts 10000 records into a table.  In case it helps, this is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Parent (
id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
xxuint1 INTEGER UNSIGNED,
xxuint2 INTEGER UNSIGNED,
xxuint3 INTEGER UNSIGNED,
xxuint4 INTEGER UNSIGNED)
```

I created a structure with values and made an array (tblParent[10000]) of 10,000 of them filled with random numbers.  Population of this array was completed before the insertions so I could measure insertion performance only.  The function below is my basic Insertion function:

```
void InsertData(sql::Connection* con)
{
    sql::PreparedStatement* pstmt = NULL;

    try {
        std::string sql = "INSERT INTO Parent("
            "xxuint1, xxuint2, xxuint3, xxuint4"
            ") VALUES (?,?,?,?);";

        pstmt = con->prepareStatement(sql);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_PARENTS; ++i) {
            pstmt->setUInt(1, tblParent[i].uint1);
            pstmt->setUInt(2, tblParent[i].uint2);
            pstmt->setUInt(3, tblParent[i].uint3);
            pstmt->setUInt(4, tblParent[i].uint4);
            pstmt->execute();
        }
    } catch(sql::SQLException &e) {
        std::cout << "SQLException: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    delete pstmt;
}
```

In general, when inserting many records, you can achieve much better performance by using multiple values lists:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), ... number_of_records
```

as opposed to inserting records one at a time.
for each number of records:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

I was assuming that the above code would use the multiple values lists method behind the scenes, but based on my performance measurements I don't believe it is.
Here's what I got:
InsertData code with 10,000 records:
~300 records / sec.
Surrounding InsertData with "START TRANSACTION" and "COMMIT":
~8000 records / sec

If I rewrite Insert Data so that I am inserting the data from the array directly into the sql as strings, e.g.

```
std::string sql = "INSERT INTO Parent("
            "xxuint1, xxuint2, xxint3, xxbigint4"
            ") VALUES (";
for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_PARENTS; ++i) {
    sql += to_string(tblParent[i].uint1) + ", ";
    sql += to_string(tblParent[i].uint2) + ", ";
    sql += to_string(tblParent[i].uint3) + ", ";
    sql += to_string(tblParent[i].uint4) + "); ";
}
```

I get similar performance as above.

Performance improved when I explicitly began using the multiple values lists. I adjusted my sql to include " VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), ..." and this improved performance to ~14,000 records / sec.  But the best times came from converting my data to strings, and inserting that data directly into the sql, using the multiple values lists.  I got up to ~40,000 records / sec doing this.

However, though the speed is fine, I don't think converting my data to text and inserting this into the sql is an ideal method.  How can I optimize my insert speed and still use the pstmt->setUint() method?

Comment: Why don't you simply use load data infile statement for this?

Comment: Because the real scenario I'm working towards is recording data given to me on the fly.  With the above problem, I am trying to find the fastest method of insertion outside of load data infile, which I realize would be the fastest if I had a file to read from.

Answer (score 0):

I did a presentation some years ago comparing the overhead of different insert methods: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast

Like you, I found that inserting multiple rows in one statement with multiple tuples in the VALUES clause is better. Your first code example does not do that by itself, you have to write the INSERT statement with multiple tuples, as in your second code example.

Avoiding a full transaction per row (i.e. autocommit) helps a lot. That's what you did when you start a transaction before the loop. There's a practical limit for the number of bytes you can insert per transaction before you break your binary logging, so if you have a very large number of inserts, try to do them in batches of, say, no more than 10k rows. I'd probably choose 1000 rows per batch to be safe. That's at least 1/1000th the overhead from transaction.

If you can reduce the number of indexes and insert triggers on the table, that will help. The cost to insert a row is approximately proportional to the number of indexes it needs to update (with some variation because of the change buffer, etc.). A trigger increases the overhead because it likely runs other DML, like inserting to log tables, which means more index writes.

Some MySQL Server tuning options can help reduce overhead a little bit, but at the cost of less data durability.

All these optimizations are dwarfed by switching to LOAD DATA INFILE, which is designed for bulk data loading. You can get something like an order of magnitude improvement this way. But there's still overhead per row due to index writes, and there's still a practical limit on the size of a transaction.

Comment: As with any performance optimization, your results may be different, depending on your system or your application.

Comment: The benefit of `LOAD DATA` is somewhat lost if you must create and write the file first.  Of course, if the data is already in a CSV file, it is a big win.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, I don't think the LOAD DATA INFILE technique is one I can use, since I don't have a file to read from.  My main concern is that it seems like to get the highest speeds, I need to first convert my data into strings so that they can be concatenated into a INSERT sql string.  I'll do that if I need to, but I was hoping to learn of a technique that didn't involve this overhead, and was still very fast.

Comment: @JasonK, I would use parameters. Then the data are never concatenated into the SQL query string.

Comment: That was what I was doing to achieve the 14,000 insertions / sec value above , but the 2.8 X performance boost I got from turning them into strings and inserting into a sql string is hard to ignore.  I was trying to find the best of both worlds where I could use parameters and still get that high speed.

Comment: I encourage you to take another look at LOAD DATA INFILE. Even if you need to write the data to a file before you can use it. It might still be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf or my.ini [mysqld] section

```
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 25 (percent) set aside in buffer pool
innodb_change_buffering=none  # from all - most likely -
innodb_write_io_threads=64  # for max capacity
```

to improve rate of inserts per second.

Reference previous answers.
dba.stackexchange.com Question 5666  see Rolando's 9/12/2011 details
dba.stackexchange.com Question 196715 look down for Rolando's change buffering
and cautions related to many aspects of these variables.